# httpd.conf file does not contain lines for "Order Deny, Allow"

Tags: server, wamp, hosting

I'm trying to host a very basic web app on my computer at home. I have wamp server installed and it's working fine in development mode. When i look at tutorials online, they all say that in order to make it public on the network, you have to change two lines that say

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
```

and make them say

```
Order Allow, Deny
Allow from all
```

I've installed two different versions of wamp (including the latest) from their official page. These lines of code do not exist in the httpd.conf file. Is there some other place I should be looking or does someone have any advice on how to create a network accessible web app? I don't need to do port forwarding on the router or anything, this is strictly for locally connected devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for http.conf in apache>conf folder. Then find AllowOverride All in httpd.conf and add these codes manually after finding that.

```
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```